# Return a generic struct which the generic type is NOT known in advance by the caller

Tags: rust

Let me retell my problem with the real use case i am doing:

```rust
use tensorflow::{
    DataType, Graph, Operation, SavedModelBundle, SessionOptions, Tensor
};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct SigMD {
    op: Operation,
    index: i32,
    dtype: DataType,
    shape: Option<Vec<Option<i64>>>,
    dims: Option<usize>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Sig {
    method_name: String,
    inputs: HashMap<String, SigMD>,
    outputs: HashMap<String, SigMD>,
}

pub struct TFModel {
    bundle: SavedModelBundle,
    sigs: HashMap<String, Sig>,
}

impl TFModel {
    pub fn load<P: AsRef<Path>>(
        saved_model_dir: P, tags: Option<&[&str]>, options: Option<&SessionOptions>,
    ) -> anyhow::Result<Self> {

        // Eventually return the loaded model instance if everything is ok.
        Ok(Self { bundle, sigs })
    }
}

pub trait Predictor {
    fn predict<Sig: AsRef<str>, K: AsRef<str>, V: AsRef<[u8]>>(
        &self, sig: Sig, inputs: &HashMap<K, V>,
    ) -> anyhow::Result<HashMap<K, Tensor<T>>>;
}

impl Predictor for TFModel {
    fn predict<Sig: AsRef<str>, K: AsRef<str>, V: AsRef<[u8]>>(
        &self, sig: Sig, inputs: &HashMap<K, V>,
    ) -> anyhow::Result<HashMap<K, Tensor<T>>>;
}
```

As you can see above i am trying to design a generic `trait Predictor` for various TensorFlow models.

After the model was loaded, the `&self` contains different `inputs` and `outputs` tensor infos for different signatures, then the `trait Predictor.predict` function takes the `&self, sig: AsRef<str>, inputs: &HashMap<AsRef<str>, AsRef<[u8]>>`, and tries to the below:

1. Use the `sig` to query the input tensor infos from the `&self`, and then convert the corresponding `AsRef<[u8]>` accordingly, like `u8 -> u16/f32`, then `reshape` etc;
2. Use the converted inputs to call [add_feed](https://tensorflow.github.io/rust/tensorflow/struct.SessionRunArgs.html#method.add_feed), and then eventually [fetch outputs](https://tensorflow.github.io/rust/tensorflow/struct.SessionRunArgs.html#method.fetch);
3. Finally return an instance of [tensorflow::Tensor](https://tensorflow.github.io/rust/tensorflow/struct.Tensor.html) if everything is ok;

I am able to get all of these work for different types of **individual** models, but i am using the concrete rust types after seeing the model `inputs/outputs` tensor infos for the model, such as:

inputs:

```json
{
    "input_tensor":"TensorInfo"{
        "op":"Operation"{
            "inner":0x7fe0e80ab048,
            "gimpl":"GraphImpl"{
                "inner":0x7fe0e800ca00,
                "owned":true
            }
        },
        "index":0,
        "dtype":UInt8,
        "shape":"Some("[
            Some(1),
            "None",
            "None",
            Some(3)
        ]")",
        "dims":Some(4)
    }
}
```

outputs:

```json
{
    "detection_anchor_indices":"TensorInfo"{
        "op":"Operation"{
            "inner":0x7fe0e80ab110,
            "gimpl":"GraphImpl"{
                "inner":0x7fe0e800ca00,
                "owned":true
            }
        },
        "index":0,
        "dtype":"Float",
        "shape":"Some("[
            Some(1),
            Some(100)
        ]")",
        "dims":Some(2)
    },
    "num_detections":"TensorInfo"{
        "op":"Operation"{
            "inner":0x7fe0e80ab110,
            "gimpl":"GraphImpl"{
                "inner":0x7fe0e800ca00,
                "owned":true
            }
        },
        "index":5,
        "dtype":"Float",
        "shape":"Some("[
            Some(1)
        ]")",
        "dims":Some(1)
    },
    "detection_classes":"TensorInfo"{
        "op":"Operation"{
            "inner":0x7fe0e80ab110,
            "gimpl":"GraphImpl"{
                "inner":0x7fe0e800ca00,
                "owned":true
            }
        },
        "index":2,
        "dtype":"Float",
        "shape":"Some("[
            Some(1),
            Some(100)
        ]")",
        "dims":Some(2)
    },
    "raw_detection_boxes":"TensorInfo"{
        "op":"Operation"{
            "inner":0x7fe0e80ab110,
            "gimpl":"GraphImpl"{
                "inner":0x7fe0e800ca00,
                "owned":true
            }
        },
        "index":6,
        "dtype":"Float",
        "shape":"Some("[
            Some(1),
            Some(1917),
            Some(4)
        ]")",
        "dims":Some(3)
    },
    "detection_boxes":"TensorInfo"{
        "op":"Operation"{
            "inner":0x7fe0e80ab110,
            "gimpl":"GraphImpl"{
                "inner":0x7fe0e800ca00,
                "owned":true
            }
        },
        "index":1,
        "dtype":"Float",
        "shape":"Some("[
            Some(1),
            Some(100),
            Some(4)
        ]")",
        "dims":Some(3)
    },
    "detection_scores":"TensorInfo"{
        "op":"Operation"{
            "inner":0x7fe0e80ab110,
            "gimpl":"GraphImpl"{
                "inner":0x7fe0e800ca00,
                "owned":true
            }
        },
        "index":4,
        "dtype":"Float",
        "shape":"Some("[
            Some(1),
            Some(100)
        ]")",
        "dims":Some(2)
    },
    "raw_detection_scores":"TensorInfo"{
        "op":"Operation"{
            "inner":0x7fe0e80ab110,
            "gimpl":"GraphImpl"{
                "inner":0x7fe0e800ca00,
                "owned":true
            }
        },
        "index":7,
        "dtype":"Float",
        "shape":"Some("[
            Some(1),
            Some(1917),
            Some(91)
        ]")",
        "dims":Some(3)
    },
    "detection_multiclass_scores":"TensorInfo"{
        "op":"Operation"{
            "inner":0x7fe0e80ab110,
            "gimpl":"GraphImpl"{
                "inner":0x7fe0e800ca00,
                "owned":true
            }
        },
        "index":3,
        "dtype":"Float",
        "shape":"Some("[
            Some(1),
            Some(100),
            Some(91)
        ]")",
        "dims":Some(3)
    }
}
```

Then i can do something like this:

```rust
let img = image::open(
    constants::LOCAL_EXT_RESOURCES_DIR_PATH.as_path().join("payloads/kirito_n_asuna.png"),
)
.unwrap();

let (w, h) = img.dimensions();

const NORM_SCALE: f32 = 1. / 255.;

let input_tensor =
    Tensor::new(&[1, w.into(), h.into(), 3]).with_values(&img.to_bytes()).unwrap();

// Or i need to convert it to Vec<f32>
// const NORM_SCALE: f32 = 1. / 255.;
// let im = image::load_from_memory(&bytes)?
//  .resize_exact(28, 28, FilterType::Nearest)
//  .grayscale()
//  .to_bytes()
//  .into_iter()
//  .map(|x| (x as f32) * NORM_SCALE)
//  .collect::<Vec<f32>>();

let mut run_args = SessionRunArgs::new();
let sig = &model.sigs["serving_default"];
println!("{:?}<<=============>>{:?}", sig.inputs, sig.outputs);
run_args.add_feed(
    &sig.inputs["input_tensor"].op,
    sig.inputs["input_tensor"].index,
    &input_tensor,
);

let num_detections_fetch = run_args
    .request_fetch(&sig.outputs["num_detections"].op, sig.outputs["num_detections"].index);

let detection_scores_fetch = run_args
    .request_fetch(&sig.outputs["detection_scores"].op, sig.outputs["detection_scores"].index);

model.bundle.session.run(&mut run_args).unwrap();

let num_detections = run_args.fetch::<f32>(num_detections_fetch).unwrap();
let detection_scores = run_args.fetch::<f32>(detection_scores_fetch).unwrap();
```

As you can see from the above code snippet i am using some concrete rust types to create the `tensorflow::Tensor<T>`, like `::<f32>` in the `let num_detections = run_args.fetch::<f32>(num_detections_fetch).unwrap();`, because after seeing the model signature i know it says for this key `num_detections` it is `"dtype":"Float",`.

**But for different models, different signature and different inputs keys, the return type could be any of these [DataTpe](https://tensorflow.github.io/rust/tensorflow/enum.DataType.html), and the return is independent from the inputs, also the caller wouldn't know in advance what actual type it will get eventually.**

**With these context, how can make the `trait Predictor.predict` function's return types be generic?**

Comment: You cannot achieve this with generics as `T`'s type would not be known at compile time, but you might be able to return a `Bar<dyn Any>` instead. The [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html) trait serves as a common supertrait for most types, akin to Java's `Object` class.

Comment: What would your calling code look like? Since you don't know what `T` is, there's nothing you do with it. What do you expect to happen if `cfg` doesn't contain `p`? Crash? The best thing to do here is to start with how you'd like to use this, and we can work forward to a solution rather than backwards from an implementation. (What you've specifically asked for is impossible; it violates the intent of the type system.)

Comment: The more I look at this, the more unclear it seems. `Foo.converter` returns a new `Bar<T>`, but `cfg` in *inside* of `Bar<T>`. So `converter` is responsible for creating `cfg`. It can't read it. How do you envision that working? Did you mean `cfg` to be passed to `converter`? Or perhaps it's supposed to be a static method on Bar rather than an instance property? What kind of values would `cfg` hold?

Comment: @RobNapier sorry, my bad, i abstracted the problem wrongly, i retell the problem with the real use case i am solving, hope this time it is clear, pls help.

Comment: I'd come back to the original question. What do you envision a *call* to `predict` to look like? What could the caller possibly do with the returned value if it could be *any* type? (It could be a WebSocket, or Void). But you don't mean that. You mean it'll be a DataType I think. So your function should always return DataType, and it's up to the caller to use `match` to deal with the resulting value in the right way. Or you could wrap it into some "DataResult" struct that offers the operations you'd want to be able to be able to perform (and implements them with lots of `match` code).

Comment: I've been messing around for about an hour messing with simpler versions of this problem. Eventually you're going to have a big `match` statement that deals with all the possible DataTypes. There's no way to have a call like `fetch::<some_variable>(...)`. That's impossible. You can have generic code like `fetch::<Output>(...)`, but `Output` is going to be a type parameter that is known at compile time.

Comment: @RobNapier thanks a lot for your time. `What could the caller possibly do with the returned value if it could be any type?`  >>> actually i am rebuilding one of my existing python TF serving project with rust, there here the return is a `Dict`, and the caller are doing one of these: 1. serialise it to json 2. serialise it to grpc 3. serialise it to customer own bin protocol 4. use it as input to invoke a customer configured post-processor 5. use it as input of the other model in graph scenario (user is responsible for the next model in the chain is compatible with the previous model's output )

Comment: If all you want is "a general bag of things I can serialize without knowing what's in it," then you want a data type that provides that. So the return value should be a `serde_json::Value` or similar "bag of unstructured data." (Serde can handle many formats, not just JSON.) Alternately, you can create your own trait to return (in a Box) that provides the interfaces you require.

Comment: @RobNapier that could only cover those serialisation cases, still have those customer configured post-processor, and use as input to the next model cases i totally have no idea how to achieve...

Comment: I recommend simplifying the problem to something that you can post here and actually complies, along with an example of what you would like to call, but can't (or show some code that you would like to de-duplicate, but can't). Ideally, something simplified so it doesn't require tensorflow, but if that's necessary, it's ok. But without something we can compile (or almost compile, except there's an error you're trying to fix), it's hard to build a solution. It's very confusing what your input and output *actually* are (in a way that we could reproduce this).

Answer (score -1):

Use an **associated type** in your trait:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Bar<T> {
    val: Option<T>,
    cfg: String
}

impl<T> Bar<T> {
    pub fn new(val: T) -> Self {
        Self {val: Some(val), cfg: "hello".to_string()}
    }
}

trait Foo {
    type DataType;
    
    fn converter<V: AsRef<[u8]>>(&self, p: String, input: V) -> Self::DataType;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4414fcba1ef0bb4e04f9ac03e4a3b399)

Using your impl as example:

```rust
impl<T> Foo for Bar<T> {
    type DataType = Bar<Vec<f32>>;
    
    fn converter<V: AsRef<[u8]>>(&self, p: String, input: V) -> Self::DataType {
        const NORM_SCALE: f32 = 1. / 255.;
        let v32 = input.as_ref()
            .into_iter()
            .map(|x| (*x as f32) * NORM_SCALE)
            .collect::<Vec<f32>>();
            
        Bar::new(v32)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for help, i use the associated type build something like this: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7c9499aee1407a375eeefb6f29f64fdc), but after this how could i implement for other DataType (Output) types?

Comment: @Inshi, maybe you need to abstract the whole return value, so the return value will actually be `Output` not `Bar<Output>`

Comment: Like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4414fcba1ef0bb4e04f9ac03e4a3b399